# How to make the MetaTrader Terminal DDE to export the FOREX rates to a Node.js server locally?

Tags: node.js, mql4, mql5

I have a Node.js server, running on my computer, and I am also running an MT4.exe at the same time.

If I can export the live rates to a simple Excel file via this scripts.

```
    BID   request: = MT4|BID!USDCHF 
    ASK   request: = MT4|ASK!USDCHF
    HIGH  request: = MT4|HIGH!USDCHF
    LOW   request: = MT4|LOW!USDCHF
    TIME  request: = MT4|TIME!USDCHF
    QUOTE request: = MT4|QUOTE!USDCHF
```

I guess this means that I can easily export the live rates to my Node.js Server too.

**How can I achieve that?**

In Excel, I only paste this code **`MT4|BID!USDEUR`** to a cell and it works and the cells gets changed every time the BID USDEUR rate changes, which makes the cell LIVE.

Comment: Is there any need to use DDE? mt4 allows `WebRequest` so you may send any data that you need to webserver - "Penguin Project" is for your needs, available with examples at Github https://github.com/PenguinTraders/MT4-Node.js/tree/master

Comment: y but when i do exactly what is described there and compile the mql code gives me 24 errors

Comment: You may show it here if you wish and we would advise what is going wrong - i suspect that you didnt upload dll files or do not allow use of dll's or didnt copy `.mqh` files into 'include' folder. Alternative way is to do Node server by yourselves and upload data using `WebRequest()` function available at mt4, instructions on how to cook it can be found at SOF, this question was discussed couple weeks ago. REST api might be more convenient then use of DDE in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes,
DDE-`request` is a possible MetaTrader Terminal integration method,
BUT ... !

given that one needs a just one-way direction of the communication and given the business domain is not any mission-critical one.

While I remember days, when interbank Money Markets trading was riding on REUTERS products, with fat add-ons for Excel spreadsheet based "analytics", but it is fair to say, that such days are forever away. Just compare how many trading events were common in those, just interbank-dealing days, prior to full opening of the FOREX trading via proxy-brokerages.

Inter-**`QUOTE`** delays were in minutes, those day.

And today?
If one sources LP-provider data-feeds, there are many units, if not **tens of PriceDOMAIN `QUOTE`-events with a single millisecond.**

---

### Got the point?
DDE is a risky per-se method for a system with `N [kTPS]` event flows
<sub>and might be happy to know, it was already effectively discontinued as late as Vista launched</sub>

In case one's business-domain is to handle a FOREX trading with an AUM's Value At Risk above a few millions of USD, no one would risk a problem of underperforming or discontinued service.

**DDE-based services have ended in the MT4 trading domain** somewhere around the Windows Vista were introduced, because it officially but indirectly terminated a use of a mix of those days commonly used DDE-services ( that were formally implemented in wV, but most of the DDE-calls were returning a **`"Not Implemented"`** Error/Response ).

This first hand acquired experience has moved the crowd to some other means of how to integrate Trading Supporting Systems and the designs simply have never returned back for reviving a service, that has caused so much pain and costs, during that nightmare experience in wV.

---

### The Best Next Step:

Supposing an above sketched Project is not a weekend hobby toy, the best sufficiently robust and platform-independet tool for such Project goals is to be defined, found and used.

One may try to revive **DDE**, but it would be a try to jump a few decades back in time.

In the same manner, one will do one's best by not losing her/his time with re-wrapping any straight app-to-app integration logic into overheads and **design/performance compromises/scape-goats** of an-artificial-**REST**-alike re-dressing of the ( very limited ) **`WebRequest()`** function calls. While there is a chance to use a `WebRequest()` not only for a **`pull-`**, but also a **quasi `push-`data** service, the costs and the http-header + the http-body payload-encoding + the full tcp/ip-stack related overheads are by far un-justifiable for the given purpose, once smarter designed tools are available

A few points for such modern tool-definition:

- **performance scaling** ( how stable it is to send 10k, 100k, 1M+ updates/s )
- **integration support** ( how many languge-bindings / platforms do support the tool )
- **thread-safe design** ( how many threads could be used ( outside the MetaTrader Terminal's restricted code-execution environment's limits ) so as to mitigate any adverse blocking or performance bottlenecks and allow some kind of fail-safe design of the distributed system processing scheme )

If need some hands-on example, one may have a look at `nanomsg`, ZeroMQ tools, and MetaTrader Terminal, which have taken over the fintech high-performance, scaleable, low-latency messaging/signalling world and grown stable/mature-enough to spend a reasonable time with.

Answer (score -3):

Use dde advise you will get rates in real time you don’t need to create dde request per second